# UI Freezing Even After Using Threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I have some lofty mathematical calculations that I need to perform without freezing my WPF UI. Here's the code I wrote to achieve it.

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            double x1_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_min.Text);
            double x1_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_max.Text);
            double x2_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_min.Text);
            double x2_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_max.Text);
            int iter = Convert.ToInt16(txtIterations.Text);
            //Data Defining and Computing
            obj.Run(x1_min, x1_max, x2_min, x2_max, iter);
            myDataGrid.ItemsSource = PSOLib.table.DefaultView;
            Minima.Text = string.Format("{0,0:0.000} ", PSOLib.min);
        }));
    });
}).Start();
```

I read many other topics on this how to unfreeze it, but I am really not well accustomed with C#'s threading model. Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You can't touch the UI from a background thread. Delete all that code and create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding and all your problems will magically disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting it on **`Dispatcher`** will run your code on UI thread only which ultimately will freeze UI. So, only put UI stuf on UI thread and run time consuming operation on secondary thread.

```
double x1_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_min.Text);
double x1_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_max.Text);
double x2_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_min.Text);
double x2_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_max.Text);
int iter = Convert.ToInt16(txtIterations.Text);

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    {
        //Data Defining and Computing
        obj.Run(x1_min, x1_max, x2_min, x2_max, iter);
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            myDataGrid.ItemsSource = PSOLib.table.DefaultView;
            Minima.Text = string.Format("{0,0:0.000} ", PSOLib.min);
        }));
    });
```

Also you can use [**BackgroundWorker**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to run time consuming operation on another thread and UI updation code *(setting ItemsSource)* in **`RunWorkerCompleted`** event of BW which runs on UI thread itself.

Comment: After running for the first time when I Click my button again the function simply doesn't work! Any ideas?

Comment: Nope no errors, but my DataGrid isn't updated. See this please [link](http://i.imgur.com/7gpYrZp.gif)

Comment: Check if `PSOLib.table` has value what you expect it because that has nothing to do with the threads. It seems issue in your code somewhere.

Comment: Nope it will change every time. See this link please [link](http://i.imgur.com/7gpYrZp.gif)

Comment: You are calculating the results with the same input values which will result in same output. Isn't it? That's why you see no update. Can you cross check by changing some inputs?

Comment: [link](http://i.imgur.com/QZL8aq5.gif) It corrupts one of the dataTable cells. Actually every iteration must be different as random numbers are used. maybe I have screwed somewhere. Thanks though.

Comment: Yeah might be issue in your `obj.Run` method. Is your GUI hanging issue resolved?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use Dispatcher.Invoke inside your parallelization constructs. At least not to such an extent.

In your original code the only real work your code inside the worker thread did was adding some Action to the Dispatcher. Your thread actually didn't make any calculation - it was just adding a task to the Dispatcher engine and ending, like:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
    { 
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(this.DoEverything));
    });
```

and this.DoEverything will not be executed on the worker thread, it will be executed on the UI background thread, thus nullyfying any advantage from the use of the worker thread.

You should complete all the calculation and only then change the UI. Otherwise it will be no more responsive if you use it directly without any parallelization.

```
 // Complete all interactions with UI to get data before using another thread
    double x1_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_min.Text);
    double x1_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_max.Text);
    double x2_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_min.Text);
    double x2_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_max.Text);
    int iter = Convert.ToInt16(txtIterations.Text);

    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((state) =>
        {
            //Data Defining and Computing that are not dependent on any UI elements
            obj.Run(x1_min, x1_max, x2_min, x2_max, iter);     
            var data = PSOLib.table.DefaultView;

            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                //Update the UI
                myDataGrid.ItemsSource = data;
                Minima.Text = string.Format("{0,0:0.000} ", PSOLib.min);
            }));
        });
```

You could actually try some another parallelization construct like [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Comment: Gives The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Comment: Sorry, I will rectify.

Comment: This has the better structure but assigning to the ItemSource could still freeze your GUI a litle. But far less, assumiomg the computations are the heavy part.

Comment: The table.DefaultView thingy (unclear where it comes from) may have to go inside the Invoke Action.

Answer (score 0):

The recommanded way of offloading CPU bounds work is via the `Task Parallel Library`. Instead of explicitly invoking `Dispatcher.Invoke` you can use a combination of `await` and `Task.Run`, or using `Task.Run` with a `ContinueWith`. Note when using `await` you will need to mark your method with the `async` keyword and have it return a `Task`

With `await`:

```
double x1_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_min.Text);
double x1_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_max.Text);
double x2_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_min.Text);
double x2_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_max.Text);
int iter = Convert.ToInt16(txtIterations.Text)

var cpuConsumingTask = await Task.Run(() => obj.Run(x1_min, x1_max, x2_min, x2_max, iter));

myDataGrid.ItemsSource = PSOLib.table.DefaultView;
Minima.Text = string.Format("{0,0:0.000} ", PSOLib.min);
```

With `ContinueWith`:

```
double x1_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_min.Text);
double x1_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x1_max.Text);
double x2_min = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_min.Text);
double x2_max = Convert.ToDouble(txt_x2_max.Text);
int iter = Convert.ToInt16(txtIterations.Text)

var cpuConsumingTask = Task.Run(() => obj.Run(x1_min, x1_max, x2_min, x2_max, iter)).ContinueWith(task => 
{
   myDataGrid.ItemsSource = PSOLib.table.DefaultView;
   Minima.Text = string.Format("{0,0:0.000} ", PSOLib.min);
},    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

I would definitely use the former, for readability and ease of use. Note the `ContinueWith` doesn't take in count exception handling which has to be added inside the continuation, while `await` will throw if an exception had occurred inside `Task.Run`